# How to display a user clicked value in another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods, view, controllers

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have a 'state' table. I have a view (say View 1) to list down all states in a country. When the user clicks on a state name he/she is taken to another view (say view 2) with the details of the selected state.

I am trying to use `find` method. But could only link up the state name (in View 1) to View 2.
Do i need to pass the state name (from view 1) to a variable and use the variable in the second view i.e, view 2?

This is in Index view

```
<% @cds.each do |cd| %>
<h5><%= link_to  cd.name :action=>:lwstlevel%></h5>
```

This is the controller .

```
def index       
    @cds = Cd.all
    end

    def lwstlevel               
    @x = Cd.find(params[:name])
    end
```

This is the in lwstlevel view

```
<h2>Welcome to  <%= @x.name %> </h>
<p> <%= @x.dscr %> </p>
```

Cd is my 'state' table. In index view if the user clicks on any state name he has to be navigated to lwstlevel view which should display details of that state.
hope this will suffice.I tried several things but none gave the desired results.

Comment: Please show some code to help explain what you're trying to accomplish. Specifically, what are you trying to do with view 2 that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<%= link_to cd.name, :action => :lwstlevel %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to cd.name, :action => :lwstlevel, :id => cd.name %>
```

and

```
def lwstlevel               
  @x = Cd.find(params[:name])
end
```

to

```
def lwstlevel               
  @x = Cd.find(params[:id])
end
```

Change name to id is id is the default for a member action, you could keep it as name however.

Comment: I am getting this Error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0).Error in line <h5><%= link_to cd.title :action => :lwstlevel, :id => cd.title %></h5>

Comment: answer edited. we've missed a comma between linkt_to cd.title and :action.

Comment: :I am facing this problem.Couldn't find Cd with id=xxxxxxxx.Parameters:{"id"=>"xxxxxxxx"}.thanks in advance

Comment: use Cd.find_by_name(params[:id]). I use find since that's what you used in our question.